# Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following:return

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I know this is another "encountered the symbol..." topic but I cannot find another like this.

```
create or replace function sendfromjar(url in varchar2, path in varchar2)
as language java
   name 'ro/myapp/sendsms.talk(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)';
```

and it raise this error:

```
    Compilation errors for FUNCTION SUMMIT1213_PTS.SENDFROMJAR

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following: return
Line: 2
Text: as language java

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

      pragma
Line: 3
Text: name 'ro/myapp/sendsms.talk(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)';
```

I am using Oracle 10g, and the jar is compiled with jdk 1.4

If I make it as a procedure it returns me

```
    Compilation errors for PROCEDURE SUMMIT1213_PTS.SENDFROMJAR

    Error: PLS-00311: the declaration of "ro/myapp/smsapp/SendSms.main(java.lang.String[])" is incomplete or malformed
Line: 3
Text: name 'ro/myapp/smsapp/SendSms.main(java.lang.String[])';

    Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated 
Line: 1 
Text: create or replace procedure sendfromjar(url in varchar2)
```

Comment: A function needs to return a value in PL/SQL. So you have to declare the return type. If it doesn't return a value (void in Java), you have to declare it as a procedure instead of as a function.

Comment: thanks, now I get

Compilation errors for PROCEDURE SUMMIT1213_PTS.SENDFROMJAR

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"
Line: 4
Text: end;

Comment: @LalitKumarB well my java method dosen't return anything (I'm calling the  main method) so I've made a procedure and it gives me the error I quoted in the original post (I've posted only the error, in code I've only replaced 'FUNCTION' with 'PROCEDURE'

Comment: @daniel.deliu `PLS-00311` AFAIK firstly, **PLS error** is a compilation error. What is the tool you are using to compile your procedure? How about trying declaring the variable, probably as shown said here http://psoug.org/oraerror/PLS-00311.htm

Comment: Not sure if relevant but you are calling ro/myapp/sendsms.talk and the error refers to ro/myapp/smsapp/SendSms. Noting the extra smsapp in the path.  Is it possible you have the class path incorrect?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I use PL/SQL Developer 10.0.5. I declared the variabile 'name' and still dosen't work

Comment: @ShaunPeterson I copied the path wrong in the post, but in PL/SQL was declared correct. Thanks for the observation

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I had to put all keywords in uppercase:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sendfromjar(url IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME  'ro/myapp/sendsms.main(java.lang.String[])';
```